# How to submit a form from another component angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I am stuck at something and I want your help.

I want to submit a form which is in another component and submit button is in another component.

How can I achieve that in angular 4?

This is my code's html.

Its form's html

```
    <form class="form form-validate" ngNativeValidate 
  (submit)="editInformationFunction($event)"
    #editForm="ngForm">
    <div class="row px-3 pb-3">

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
    <!---------------Panel1 ------------------->
    <div class="panel panel-primary radius">
      <div class="panel-heading border-bottom p-2">
        <h3 class="panel-title m-0"><i class="fa fa-user green pl-3"> 
   </i> <span
          class="ml-2 font-weight-bold">PERSONAL INFORMATION</span> . 
   </h3>
        <span class="pull-right "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
    chevron-down"> </i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">

          <!--input fields-->

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 
    ">
            <div class="form-group mt-4 ml-4">
              <label for="name"><b>NAME<span class="text-danger ml-2">* 
    </span> </b></label>
              <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                     [(ngModel)]="editInformationModel.name"
                     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 
    ">
            <div class="form-group mt-4 mr-4">
              <label for="info"><b>BIRTH DATE
              </b></label>
              <input id="info" type="text" class="form-control"
                     [(ngModel)]="editInformationModel.birthdate ? 
     editInformationModel.birthdate : N/A "
                     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group form-check-inline mt-1 ml-4">
              <b>GENDER<span class="text-danger ml-2">*</span></b>

              <div class="form-check-inline d-flex mt-1">

                 <label class="customradio"><span class="radiotextsty"> 
     <b>Male</b></span>
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio"
                         [(ngModel)]="editInformationModel.sex"
                         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
   value="m">
                  <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                </label>
                <label class="customradio ml-2"><span 
    class="radiotextsty"><b>Female</b></span>
                  <input type="radio" name="radio"
                         [(ngModel)]="editInformationModel.sex"
                         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
    value="f">
                  <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                </label>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Its forms .ts file

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-information',
styleUrls: ['./edit-information.component.css'],
templateUrl: './edit-information.component.html'
})
export class EditInformationComponent implements OnInit { 
editInformationFunction(e) {
  console.log(this.editInformationModel);  
 this.editInformationService.editMemberInformation
 (this.editInformationModel).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.spinner.hide();
    if (response ['error'] == false) {
      console.log(response);
      this.toastr.success(response['data'], 
this.editInformationData.toastTitle.success);
    } else {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.toastr.error(response['message'], 
this.editInformationData.toastTitle.error);
    }
  },
  err => {
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.toastr.error(err.error['message'], 
this.editInformationData.serverError);
    }
   )
  }
}
```

its my sidebar html from where i want to submit my form....

```
  <div class="d-flex" [hidden]="saveInformation">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm py-2 border-0"><i 
 class="fa fa-save"> </i>
    Save
    Information
  </button>
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm text-white ml-2 py-2" 
  routerLink="/household-information">
     Cancel
  </button>
  </div>
```

Its sidebar's .ts file

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-sidebar',
 styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html'
 })
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your components are at time the easer way is using @Input and pass your component in a reference variable.
e.g.
You app.component is like

```
<hello #hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<nav-bar [component]="hello"></nav-bar>
```

//Your nav-bar is like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  template: `<button (click)="click()">click me</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class NavBarComponent  {
  @Input()component:any
  click()
  {
    console.log(this.component.variable)
  }
}
```

The "clasic" is use a service. Your service can be like

```
@Injectable()

export class DataService {

  private mySubjectSource = new Subject<any>();
  myObservable=this.mySubjectSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  sendValue(value:any)
  {
    this.mySubjectSource.next(value);
  }
}
```

Then your component use this service:

The component that emit a value

```
export class NavBarComponent  {
  constructor(private service:DataService){}
  click2()
  {
    this.service.sendValue("save data")
  }
}
```

The component that receive the event

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service:DataService){  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.service.myObservable.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
}
```

in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2ednv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) I put the two ways

Choose where you want to make the submit: In you nav getting the value of the form, or in the form when you emit a event from the nav-

Comment: will it work with form? like where we have to submit a function?

Comment: Usman, if you choose call to the service in the component that has the form, you subscribe in the component and, in subscription, you can call to any function of your component. If you choose call the service in the nav-bar, you has the value of the form in component.editInformationModel.value

Comment: i applied this code but my form is submitting multiple times means i get success msg at 1st two times the 4 times and so on 
i dont know why @Eliseo

Comment: When use a getter Angular execute the getter several times along life of the component. It's because we must use carefully. That's has no importane if it's about recover the value of a variable or something like. If you use a Subject that shouldn't happen

Comment: can you see my latest post about this topic? @Eliseo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062969/when-i-submit-a-from-whose-button-is-in-another-component-it-submits-several-ti

Answer (score 0):

**My understanding:**
1) When you click 'Submit' in sidebar's HTML, you would like to execute the function  'editInformationFunction' in the form's ts file.

2) I don't see 'app-sidebar' being included in the form's HTML and so I assume they are siblings. So there is no direct parent-child relationship here.

3) editInformationModel - This is the key variable that you use inside the 'editInformationFunction'.

**Solution:**
What you need is an '**event emitter**'. It can easily solve your problem.

i) You can emit an event from your app-sidebar and catch it in your parent component (app-component.html, say)

ii) Then you can invoke the desired function in the form's ts file from the parent component.

This blog will help you. https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/08/31/angular-4-and-sibling-component-interaction/

I had a similar use case. This method worked 100% and was quite simpler.

Comment: Thank you brother :) 
i will read that blog and btw <app-sidebar> is included in form html

Comment: Welcome. However, the code that is posted in here does not have that app selector when I did a Ctrl+F in form HTML. Well, if app-sidebar is a child of form, then you can go with the @Input binding as mentioned by Eliseo.