# How to pass a value from html to be use from other component functions Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing, frontend, event-binding

I have a dropdown and I want to pass the Id of the selected value (**$event.target.value**) in other component functions.

```
 <div class="dropdown  ml-auto">
   <select  (change)=getSelectedVariantProject($event.target.value)>
      <option value = "default">Select project</option>
      <option *ngFor = "let project of selectProject" value = {{project.projectId}}>{{project.projectName}}</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

I have project service with these two functions:

```
getProjects(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<Project>(this.urlProject)
    .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('getProject',[]))
  );
  }

  getProjectVariant(id: number): Observable<any>{
    var url = this.urlProjectVariant;
    url = url + id;
    return this.http.get<ProjectVariant>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getProjectVariant',[]))
      )
  }
```

And I have table component in which I need the id value from HTML in argument projectVariantId :

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {

  filters: MisraLint;
  pageMisraMessages: PageMisraLintTable;
  selectedPage : number = 0;
  buildId: number = 1;
  sizeTableEntries: number = 100;
  page: any;

  constructor(private misraService: MisraService) { }

  getFilters(): void{  
    this.misraService.getMisraLintFilters(2)
      .subscribe(filters => this.filters = filters);
  }

  getPageMisra(page:number,projectVariantId: number,size:number,buildId:number): void{
    this.misraService.getPageMisraLint(page,projectVariantId, size,buildId)
      .subscribe(pageMisra => {
        this.pageMisraMessages = pageMisra
        console.log("Misra meessgaes: " + pageMisra.content)
      })

  }

  getMisraLintByFilters(page: number, projectVariantId: number, size:number, filter: string)
  {
       //call rest API to apply filters
   this.misraService.getMisraLintByFilters(page,projectVariantId,size,filter)
   .subscribe(pageMisra => {
     this.pageMisraMessages = pageMisra
   })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFilters();
    this.getPageMisra(0,2,this.sizeTableEntries,this.buildId);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to do this. How to pass **$event.target.value** because I need this value as an argument of other component functions(in typescript) when the users choose something from the dropdown.

Comment: share components code as well for better understanding.

Comment: I put the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1.) If you are using other component on same page than**

In component.ts

```
selectedProject = null;

getSelectedVariantProject(id){
 this.selectedProject = id;
}
```

in component.html

```
<app-other-component selectedProject="selectedProject"></app-other-component>
```

in otherComponent.ts

```
@Input() selectedProject;
```

**Approach 2.) OR other component is on other page than you can use service.**

In component

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

}

getSelectedVariantProject(id){
     this.someService.selectedProject = id;
}
```

in otherComponent.ts

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
 console.log(this.someService.selectedProject);
}
```

Comment: for the first approach is better use a "reference variable", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801079/how-to-submit-a-form-from-another-component-angular-4/53803465#53803465

Answer (score 0):

You have: `<select (change)=getSelectedVariantProject($event.target.value)>`

You could add a variable on your component end. Such as selectedvariant or something, or straight away use it on the function like:

`getSelectedVariantProject(val){//code here}` Note that (val) is your $event.target.value.

Example:

`selectedvariant:any = val;`

or

`if(condition === condition_equal_to_whatever`***`val`***`usage`

Read more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

Comment: I did not understand how note that(val) is my $event.target.value.

Comment: which mean the `(change)=getSelectedVariantProject($event.target.value)` was unused before you declare `getSelectedVariantProject(val)` to get the value of the event being fired which is the select change.

Comment: If you could add a working codepen/stackblitz snippet it would help tremendously toward answering your query. But one of the easiest method to use it is as I stated above.